# Angular ASP.NET Core Chart.js bug on chart rebuild when filtering the list of values

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined.

I have a method which builds a chart in my app. That happens OnInit

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels :this.equity,
    datasets: [{
      data: this.equity
    }]
  }
});
```

}

this.equity is an array of values that I calculate on the client side using data from the server. That is the list that I filter later on.

Everything builds smoothly untill I start filtering. The chart is built upon values in a list. I have coded a filter that filters the list with various options. At the end of each filtering I call the method above again to rebuild the chart.

Now here is where strange things start to happen. The chart rebuilds smoothly. I filter many times with different options and then at some point boom I get this error! It doesn't occur at some particular moment when I'm pressing on the filter, it just occurs.

I think it is because every time I create a new chart object and supply it with new values. The variable for the values is the same as for the old object and that causes an error because at some point Angular checks out the old object and it has already got a new list of values which doesn't match the old list.

Has this hapened to anyone? Does anybody now how do I null out the old chart object at the point when I create a new chart object so this possibly solves? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try destroying the old chart instance before creating a new one, using the [**`destroy()`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy) method.

```
...
if (myChart) myChart.destroy();
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'line',
         ...
...
```

<sup>make sure the `myChart` variable is globally accessible</sup>

However, a better approach would be to update your chart using the [**`update()`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) method, when you add/update any data in your chart, instead of creating a new instance of chart everytime.

Comment: Thank you. Seems this is working. It also seems that you should destroy the chart object when navigating away from the page (component) because now I am not getting errors on filtering but if I navigate away and come back they appear after a while.

Comment: Yes! So far so good. Update() on filtering and use this if (myChart) myChart.destroy(); OnInit().